# How to clear my Layout Cache in Liferay

Tags: java, caching, layout, liferay

I have a problem with my Liferay Cache.

**Scenario :**
I am reading an XML file and importing layouts to my Liferay DB using Liferay API.

There is huge data being stored in the ***typeSettings*** column of the layout.

**Problem :**
When I am importing around 5000 layouts, I get an **OutofMemoryException**.
I could find the most retained Heap Space is by the **EhCache object**.
(which holds the LayoutCacheModel with my huge typesettings)

Is it a good idea to clear the cache after each layout import ?

If so, how can I clear the cache specific to layouts. (I am using **Liferay 6.0**)

Thanks,

Siby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the answer given by *@ramsinb* I was able to clear the cache using code from :

**LayoutPersistenceImpl.java**

```
public void clearCache() {
    if (_HIBERNATE_CACHE_USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE) {
        CacheRegistryUtil.clear(LayoutImpl.class.getName());
    }

    EntityCacheUtil.clearCache(LayoutImpl.class.getName());
    FinderCacheUtil.clearCache(FINDER_CLASS_NAME_ENTITY);
    FinderCacheUtil.clearCache(FINDER_CLASS_NAME_LIST);
}
```

I had to manually copy this code as its not available as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Before you look at flushing ehcache (probably best not to do it after each import rather after every couple of hundred), look at the JVM settings you have and consider increasing the maximum heap size allocated to the JVM running the portal. E.g. -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Furthermore you should look at [Liferay's](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/performance-tuni-4) website for performance tuning the portal (although I'm not sure what version you are using).

Given you have already configured your JVM settings you can look at flushing the ehcache after X loads (I still suggest that you flush it after >1 loads as opposed to ever load). You can get a handle to the `CacheManager` with the following and flush it:

```
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();
manager.removalAll();
```

I've never done this in Liferay myself however thought it might still be of some benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No this is done as an interval job. Basically I dont need the layout to be maintained by cache after a successful import. (I have already configured my maximum heap size)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emptying the cache completely, you can also configure the cache size. Monitor the JMX data to determine how big your actual cache is, and adopt according to your needs. Some documentation for cache configuration is https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/ehCache+Configuration and https://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Caching+%28EhCache%29 - I expect more to be available in the User's Guide.

Comment: Hi Olaf...Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I am trying to do right now. But in the <cache>, how can we configure the cache size ? I could only find maxElementsInMemory (<-- I dont want to limit the number as sizes can vary) and overFlowToDisk.